# como pasar y cambiar el valor de una variable pasando por funciones [TYPESCRIPT]

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic, ionic4

Estoy intentando cambiar el valor de una variable que pasa por un $.post que a su vez este esta dentro de una funcion.

```
export class IndexPage implements OnInit {
    contentPage: number = 0;
    constructor () {}
    ngOnInit () {
        this.loadMainContent ();
    }
    loadMainContent () {
        $.post ( url, data, function ( d ) {
            this.contentPage++;
        });
    }
}
```

La variable 'contentPage' no suma, sigue teniendo siempre el mismo valor. Como se maneja esto?

Comment: has probado utilizar **HttpClient**

Comment: ¿Ya has depurado con un `console.log(this)` dentro de tu función `callback` donde intentas realizar el incremento de la variable?

Comment: Si, en console.log siempre me devuelve 'undefined' y en HttpClient me da error

Comment: estas seguro que la peticion a url se hace bien ? Ya que la funcion solo se ejecuta si la peticion es success. Te recomiendo usar observables en angular dan mas potencia que las peticiones de jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es la función anónima que creas y pasas como callback de `$.post`. Al hacerlo de esa manera, `this` hace referencia a la función y no al contexto, por lo que contentPage no existe. Compruébalo haciendo `console.log(this)` dentro de la callback.

Si quieres hacer uso de variables que se encuentran en el contexto te recomiendo hacer uso de las arrow functions (funciones flecha), las cuales por diseño `this` hace referencia al contexto. El código sería algo así:

```
export class IndexPage implements OnInit {
    contentPage: number = 0;
    constructor () {}
    ngOnInit () {
        this.loadMainContent ();
    }
    loadMainContent () {
        $.post ( url, data, ( d ) => {
            this.contentPage++;
        });
    }
}
```

Incluso podrías quitar los brackets para que quede aún mas sencillo:

```
[...]

    loadMainContent () {
        $.post ( url, data, d => this.contentPage++ );
    }

[...]
```